# Bootstrap: Bad style to not use col when there would be only a col-12?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it bad style (or even dangerous) to only use

```
 <div class="row">Text</div>
```

instead of

```
 <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">Text</div></div>
```

when there are not more than one columns needed?

Comment: How would it be “dangerous”?

Comment: Dangerous as if the responsiveness does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `.row` usually has negative margins to offset the outer-most `.col` left/right padding. Compare these two instances with and without `.col` use.

With `.col`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container"><div class="row bg-primary"><div class="col">This text is inside row > col</div></div></div>
```

Without `.col`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container"><div class="row bg-primary">This text is inside row</div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Good answer.